# Remove tags from dependent term ref field when dependee is deactivated

Tags: taxonomy-terms, entities

I have a check box acting as the dependee. When it is checked, it opens up a free-tagging term-reference field. So when `A` is checked, `B` appears and users can add tags:

`A (checkbox): []
  B (tags): [________]`

In the settings I have the following selected:

> "Reset the dependent to its default values when the form is submitted
>   if the dependency is not triggered."

The default value for the term-ref field is blank. When the checkbox (dependee) is unchecked and the content saved, it should revert to the default value. However, all added terms remain.

Is there a way to remove all taxonomy terms in this scenario? I have multiple dependee/dependent fields in the content type, so it would have to act independently of other fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed...

In the conditional fields settings I had used the following:

> - The dependent field is: visible
> - When the dependee: is checked

For some reason this does not revert the dependent to its default value if the dependee is deactivated on saving. Instead, I used these settings and it works:

> - The dependent field is: visible
> - When the dependee: is has value
> - (select the name of the checkbox)

This might be because I have used the label as the value for the checkboxes (instead of the default 0 & 1).